# How to prove that $t=0$ or $t=2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The following is from Gardiner's *The Mathematical Olympiad Handbook*

> In contrast, if $t$ and $a$ are integers, then a factorization such as $t^{2}=a(t-1)$ tells you a lot because $t-1$ must then be a factor of $t^{2}$! But two consecutive integers, such as $t-1$ and $t$, always have a highest common factor equal to $1$, so there are only two possible ways in which $t-1$ can divide $t^{2}$, namely, if $t$=____ or if $t$=____.

So, the answers to the blanks are $t = 0,2$. But my problem is understanding how one arrives at those answers using the information that $t-1$ and $t$ always have a $gcd=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $t-1$ divides $t^2$ (assumption) and $t-1$ divides $(t-1)(t+1) = t^2-1$, we know that $t-1$ divides $t^2-(t^2-1) = 1$. Therefore, $t-1 = \pm1$ and $t=0$ or $t=2$.